# Do Java Lambda Expressions Utilize "Hidden" or Local Package Imports?

Tags: java, lambda

This question is about the apparent "hidden" or local imports of Java packages that lambda expressions seem to employ.

The following sample code compiles and runs fine (it just lists the files in the given directory):

```
package com.mbm.stockbot;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Temp2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Temp2 t = new Temp2();
        t.readDir();
    }

    public void readDir() {
        try {
            Files.walk(Paths.get("C:/Users/mbmas_000/Downloads/SEC Edgar"), 1).forEach(filePath -> {
                if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
                    System.out.println(filePath);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the variable `filePath` is an instance of `Path`, whose implementation I think is contained in package `java.nio.file.Path`, although there is no `import` for that package.

Now, if I make a small modification, say by refactoring the call to `System.out.println` to its own method:

```
package com.mbm.stockbot;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Temp2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Temp2 t = new Temp2();
        t.readDir();
    }

    public void readDir() {
        try {
            Files.walk(Paths.get("C:/Users/mbmas_000/Downloads/SEC Edgar"), 1).forEach(filePath -> {
                if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
                    printPath(filePath);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void printPath(Path passedFilePath) {
        System.out.println(passedFilePath);
    }
}
```

I must now 'import' `import java.nio.file.Path`, otherwise I get a compiler error.

So my questions are:

1. If `filePath` is indeed an instance of `java.nio.file.Path`, why *don't* I need to import it in the first example, and
2. If using the lambda expression performs the import "under the covers," then why *do* I need to add the `import` when I create a method that takes an instance of `Path` as an argument?

The methods available to call on both `filePath` and `passedFilePath` are identical, leading me to believe they are both instances of `java.nio.file.Path`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`import` declarations are not meant to declare what classes your code is using; they just declare what to use to resolve unqualified identifiers. So if you are using the unqualified identifier `Path` in your code you have to use `import java.nio.file.Path;` to declare that it should get resolved to this qualified type. This is not the only way to resolve a name, by the way. Names can also get resolved through the class inheritance, e.g. if they match the simple name of an inherited member class.

If you are using a type implicitly without referring to its name you don’t need an `import` statement, that’s not limited to lambda expressions, it is not even a special Java 8 feature. E.g. with

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("C:/Users/mbmas_000/Downloads/SEC Edgar"), 1)
```

you are already using the `Path` type implicitly as it’s the return type of `Paths.get` and a parameter type of `Files.walk`, in other words, you are receiving an instance of `java.nio.file.Path` and passing it to another method without referring to its type name, hence you don’t need an `import`. Further you are calling a varargs method accepting an arbitrary number of `FileVisitOption` instances. You are not specifying any, therefore your code will create a zero-length `FileVisitOption[]` array and pass it to `Files.walk`, again, without an `import`.

With the improved type inference, there is another possibility to use a type without referring to its name, e.g. if you call:

```
Files.newByteChannel(path, new HashSet<>());
```

You are not only creating a zero length `FileAttribute[]` array for the varargs parameter without referring to this type by name, you are also creating a `HashSet<OpenOption>` without referring to the type `OpenOption` by name. So this also doesn’t require neither, importing `java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute` nor `java.nio.file.OpenOption`.

---

So the bottom line is, whether you need an `import` does not depend on the use of the type but whether you refer to it by its simple name (and there are more than one way to use a type without referring to it by name). In your second example you are referring to the name `Path` in your method `printPath(Path passedFilePath)`; if you change it to `printPath(Object passedFilePath)`, everything will work again without an explicit `import` of `java.nio.file.Path`.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that in the second example, you declare a local variable `Path passedFilePath` (as a method parameter). When you do this, you need an `import` to tell the java compiler which type `Path` you mean, because multiple packages can have a class with the same name. You might have noticed that when you create a variable `List something` and ask the IDE to auto-create the import, most IDEs will usually ask you if you mean `java.util.List` or `java.awt.List`. You could also create an own class `com.myorg.myproject.List` which would then be a third option.

In the first example the exact type of `filePath` is determined by the type required by `Paths.get(...).forEach`, so you don't need to tell the java compiler which `class Path` you refer to.

By the way, you could omit the import in the second example, when you would rewrite the method signature as `public void printPath(java.nio.file.Path passedFilePath)`. When providing a fully qualified class name, you don't need an import anymore because the class-name can not be ambiguous.

You might wonder "but why do I need an import or fully qualified name when there is only one class named `Path` in the whole standard library and I don't have an own class of that name?" - remember that Java is designed for code re-usability. When your code is used in another project, that project might have such a class or might use a 3rd-party library which has and then your code would be ambiguous.

Comment: He does declare a `filePath` variable of type `Path`, that's the point of his question.  The lambda definition with `filePath` is of that type, but requires no import.  It's simply an optional syntax in Java 8 that doesn't require you to write the `Path` type on the variable definition

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an import in the second example because you are declaring a variable.

This doesn't have anything to do with lambda expressions. You would have exactly the same thing happen if you used an anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point you're trying to illustrate can be simplified like this:

This lambda *requires* an import

`Paths.get("path").forEach((Path filePath) -> {});`

This lambda *does not require* an import

`Paths.get("path").forEach((filePath) -> {});`

Since `Path.forEach(...)` takes a `Consumer<? super Path>` I presume the latter case is creating a new type on-the-fly of `? super Path`, and thus you don't need an import since it's a new type (like a generic type at runtime)