# Are some import statements not required with local type inference?

Tags: java, import, var, type-inference, java-10

Assuming I have the following class that defines a single `static` utility method:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel;

public class Utility {
    public static AsynchronousSocketChannel getChannel() {
        try {
            return AsynchronousSocketChannel.open();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
}
```

I am then able to create a class (located in the same package as `Utility`) that utilizes this method:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        var channel = Utility.getChannel();
        System.out.println(channel);
        channel.close();
    }
}
```

However, `Test` seems to not require any import statements, even though it uses `AsynchronousSocketChannel` locally.  If I were to have typed `AsynchronousSocketChannel channel = ...;` instead, then the import statements would be required, obviously.

Is my assumption that import statement(s) are *inferred* at compile-time (when taking advantage of local type inference) correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`import` statements are a purely syntactical construct; they just allow you to refer to a typename without writing its full package name.

In particular, they have nothing to do with loading anything.

If you never explicitly use the typename in code, you don't need the import.

Comment: Somehow I forgot that!  Would that mean that `var channel = Utility.getChannel();` is synonymous with `java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel channel = Utility.getChannel();`?

Comment: @JacobG.: Yes; this is all syntactic sugar.

Comment: See also “[Do Java Lambda Expressions Utilize “Hidden” or Local Package Imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28180695/2711488)”, as using types without referring to them by name (and hence not needing `import` statements) is much older…

Comment: @SLaks that is not really syntactic sugar, it's a compile inferred typed, there are types that you can't declare due to the language, but could be inferred by the compiler... `var test = new Object(){
            int x = 3;  
        };
        
        int y = test.x;`